Equivalent definition of a smooth curve on a manifold
Reading a beginner book on manifolds, I came across the following characterization of a smooth curve:
A function $\gamma: (a,b) \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map (between two manifolds) iff for every $q \in N$, there is some chart $(V,\psi)$ about $q$ and some open interval $(c,d) \subset (a,b)$ such that $\gamma(c,d) \subset V$ and
$$ \psi \circ \gamma: (c,d) \rightarrow \psi(V) $$
is a smooth function in the usual sense.
My definition of a smooth map is standard, i.e., it is given by well-known books by Tu or Lee. The thing I dont understand is that $q$ can be anywhere, not in the image $\gamma(a,b)$. In this post, I would like to prove the necessary part, here is my try.
To show $\gamma$ is smooth, we need to find chart $(U,\phi)$ about an arbitrary point $x \in (a,b)$ and chart $(O,\varphi)$ about $\gamma(x)$ such that $ \varphi \circ \gamma \circ \phi^{-1} $ is smooth. Natural choice is $(U,\phi) =((a,b),id_{(a,b)})$. We need to choose $(O,\varphi)$ as well. From the hypothesis, we can find chart $(V,\psi)$ about $q = \gamma(x)$ and some open interval $(c,d) \subset (a,b)$ such that $\gamma(c,d) \subset V$ and
$$ \psi \circ \gamma: (c,d) \rightarrow \psi(V) $$
is a smooth function in the usual sense. However, there is no guarantee that $x \in (c,d)$ at all. The set $V$ can contain $\gamma(c,d)$ and $\gamma(x)$ at the same time but they can be far away (disjoint) for example. How do we resolve this? Or maybe there is some mistake in the book on this equivalence? Thank you in advance!
Also, I have a funny proof for the sufficient part: Take any $q\in N$ and one $x \in (a,b)$. Since $\gamma$ is a smooth map, we can find $(U,\phi)$ (we can choose $((a,b),id_{(a,b)})$ ) about $x$ and $(V,\psi)$ about $\gamma(x)$ such that $\psi \circ \gamma \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth. Take one chart $(O,\varphi)$ about $q$ such that $O \cap V = \emptyset$. Define the new chart $(V',\psi')$ as $V' = O \cup V$, and $\psi' =\psi$ on $V$ and $\psi' = \varphi$ on $O$, then this is a chart about $q$ that satisfies the above property. So this is another reason showing the statement could be wrong....

Can you print the "well-known" definition please?

@rushusuixing, I also wrote that in the question: "To show $\gamma$ is smooth...."

Where sid you find this definition? It is simply wrong as written. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

@MoisheKohan I found it on page 236 in the book Differential geometry and Lie groups, A computational approach - Jean Gallier , Jocelyn Quaintance. This is Definition 8.9, I only replace "$C^k$-function" with "smooth function" here...

OK, then you should ignore their definition and use the standard one which you will find in many differential topology textbooks.

@MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your advice, I would do so then :). I feel so sad wasting my time writing this question without knowing it couldn't be fixed....

See for instance the definition given in this or this question (and answers).

The authors correctly define the concept of a $C^k$-map$f : M \to N$ between manifolds and prove a theorem giving some equivalent characterizations.
Then they consider two special cases:

$N = \mathbb R$.

In form of a definition they state

A function $f : M \to \mathbb R$ is a $C^k$-map iff for every $p \in M$, there is some chart $(U,\varphi)$ at $p$ so that $f \circ \varphi^{-1} : U \to \mathbb R$ is a $C^k$-function.

This is correct, but in my opinion it is inappropriate to call this a definition - it is a theorem. Before stating the above "definition" the authors themselves write "One checks immediately that a function $f : M \to \mathbb R$ is a $C^k$-map iff the following condition holds". It is proved by taking the canonical chart $id : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ at $f(p)$ for all $p \in M$.
Actually it does not make sense to work with two definitions, one for the general case and one for a special case. Both definitions agree in the special case (if this were not the case it would be a mess to use the phrase $C^k$-map in both situations).

$M = (a,b)$, an open interval of $\mathbb R$.

For $C^k$-maps $(a,b) \to N$ one uses the phrase "$C^k$-curve in $N$". Again the authors write "One checks immediately that a function $\gamma : (a, b) \to N$ is a $C^k$-map iff the following condition holds". This condition is that occurring as a definition in your question, and again it should be called a theorem. Unfortunately it is wrong.
We know that $\gamma : (a, b) \to N$ is a $C^k$-map iff there are some charts $(U,\varphi)$ at $p \in (a,b)$ and $(V, \psi)$ at $\gamma(p)$ with $\gamma(U) \subset V$, such that the function $\psi \circ \gamma \circ  \varphi^{-1} : \varphi(U) \to  \psi(V)$ is a $C^k$-function. Of course it suffices to take special charts of the form $id : (p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon) \to  (p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)$ at $p$ with sufficiently small $\epsilon$. But we cannot expect that the image of $\gamma$ in contained in the domain of a single chart on $N$. Thus the best we can do is stating

$\gamma : (a, b) \to N$ is a $C^k$-curve iff for $p \in (a,b)$ there exist an open subinterval $(c, d)$ of $(a, b)$ with $p \in (c,d)$ , and a chart $(V, \psi)$ at $\gamma(p)$ with $\gamma(c,d) \subset V$, such that $\psi \circ \gamma : (c,d) \to \psi(V)$ is a $C^k$-function.

It is not expedient to consider charts at arbitrary $q  \in N$ as the authors did. It is not even expedient to consider charts at all $q \in  \gamma(a,b)$. It essential to consider all points $p \in (a,b)$ and then find $(c,d)$ and $(V, \psi)$ as above.
The only case where it can be simplified is if there exists a chart $(V, \psi)$ on $N$ with $\gamma(a,b) \subset V$. Then

$\gamma : (a, b) \to N$ is a $C^k$-curve iff $\psi \circ \gamma : (a,b) \to \psi(V)$ is a $C^k$-function.

Update.
Another variant is this:

A continuous $\gamma : (a, b) \to N$ is a $C^k$-curve if for every $q \in N$, there is some chart $(V, \psi)$ at $q$ such that $\psi \circ \gamma : \gamma^{-1}(V) \to \psi(V)$ is a $C^k$-function.

If $q \notin \gamma(a,b)$, then $\gamma^{-1}(V)$ may be empty, but this is no problem. If $q \in \gamma(a,b)$, then $\gamma^{-1}(V)$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$ containing all $p \in (a,b)$ mapped to $q$.

Thanks Paul! This is very helpful for me!
